# Getting "Incorrect range height" in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Am trying to get the url's printed in a column and am getting this error:
"Incorrect range height,was 1 but should be 132 (line 37, file "Code")"

and when am getting the url in debugger, am getting it in this form:

"http\://myrul.com\:8080/abcde/" and i have more than 130+ urls which am getting from API. now my second concern is i wanna somehow split and get the url in this form:
"http://myrul.com:8080/abcde/"
(remove all the backslash's from all the 130 urls)

hope u guys can help
Thanks

here is the function that i have written:

`

```
function fetchFromApi() {
  var url = '<<my api from where am fetching the data>>';
  var urlResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var urlResult = JSON.parse(urlResponse);
  var key = Object.keys(urlResult);
  var tempArr = [];
  for (var x in urlResult) {
  var value = urlResult[x];
  tempArr.push(value)
  }
  inputSheet.getRange(2,6,tempArr.length,1).setValues([tempArr]);
  Logger.log(tempArr);
}
```

`

Comment: Could you please point on the line (37) where error happens in your code snippet?

Comment: inputSheet.getRange(2,6,tempArr.length,1).setValues([tempArr]);

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160707/incorrect-range-height-google-script)

Comment: thanks for the help. can u help me with the second part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part please use the following regex

```
value.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

Please insert it inside your loop.

Please see how it works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/leugenel/2uLdzkm7/)